# Can't install apt-file and ubuntu tweak in terminal

Tags: software-installation, 10.10

I tried to install the packages `apt-file`, `ubuntu-tweak` and `checkinstall` using `sudo apt-get install <package name>` in 10.10, but the terminal reported `package not found` even after `sudo apt-get update`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you don't have the universe or multiverse repositories enabled - not all software is in the core ubuntu distribution.  Luckily, it's simple to enable those from the system menu:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Additionally, even though those are command line programs, you can install them from the ubuntu software center or another graphical package manager.

Comment: I enabled the universe and multiverse repository sources and it works thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken ubuntu-tweak is in it's own repository -- at least it always was. You can download the deb at http://ubuntu-tweak.com/ and then using ubuntu-tweak add it's PPA to insure it stays updated.

Comment: i had the deb file from the site you cited but how do i add PPA to stay updated? sudo apt-get  update got me ubuntu tweak in the software centre.